# "how do i solve this logical problem" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Across all the subjects applicable to this site I think we have 2 large groups of questions:

- I'm trying to do X and run into problem Y.
- I don't know how I should do X.

the first category is usually tagged quite specifically, as posters know what they are trying to find a solution for. The second category, in my opinion is often tagged to general and vague with things like "force.com","apex", "salesforce" and I think we could try to steer to give these type of questions a separate tag maybe (though I'd not know how to name it).

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 6):

I think it is OK to have both fine grained and broad subject tags.  There is no tag hierarchy, so people who are interested in a broad subject can subscribe to the broader tag and those that are interested in something more finer grained can limit what they want to see to the more specific tags.

My thought is that if you see that a question can get a more specific tag, then edit the question and give it more specific tag, but leave the broader tag if it is applicable.

In my opinion if, using your judgement and experience, think that a tag should be created then go for it.

There's a section in the [tagging help](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) on avoiding the use of [meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).  We should avoid creating tags like 'beginner' or 'simple', etc., or creating tags to further classify other tags, like 'beginner salesforce', 'advanced salesforce' 'specific salesforce', or 'general salesforce' and just leave them as force.com or platform, etc.

You can also [create tag synonyms](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).

Comment: "My thought is that if you see that a question can get a more specific tag, then edit the question and give it more specific tag,"  This is exactly my question, what if that one doesn't exist yet, and i'm unsure if it should.

Comment: Ah.  OK.  I updated my answer.